# Cause of lagging process execution

Tags: linux, hard-drive, process, bash-scripting

I am running two programs.

One python program which generates a set of large files and writes them to an external hard drive I have mounted to the computer.

The second is a bash script which cleans the files by concatenating them in some way.

I noticed in "htop" first during the program execution and later during the "cat" commands in my bash script that the computer is just stopping the execution of the commands and then starting it over and over, so it is taking far longer than I would expect and lagging/shutting down the multithreading in the python program. This is despite not using all(or even much) of the CPUs/RAM on the machine.

What could be the cause of this start/stop of the process?

Comment: are you sure its starting over? this sounds like a context switch to process another thread while a IO request is running, and its waiting for a DMA callback before resuming. are your scripts threaded?

Comment: @FrankThomas, Stop was I guess the wrong word, but it does seem to be "freezing" for a while for no reason. The python script is threaded, but the bash script is not. Both seem to have the problem.

Comment: most IO devices can do exactly one thing at a time. what does iotop say?

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you, so it is useless to try and parallelize file writing?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. depends on a lot, and its not really an appropriate topic for this site. are you seeing consistent IO in iotop while the program appears to be frozen?

Comment: @FrankThomas I just relaunched the program. I saw some strange things in IOtop as well. Basically I run the program on 24 threads and I see that for each generated process in iotop they also have the same freeze, stop, and go pattern and only 3 or 4 proccesses are reading/writing at a time with speeds of around 200kb/s, which seems low.  During these freeze times the CPUs also stop maxing out. However, there are also "go' times when 2/3 of the processes read in 5-8 Mb/s so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: @GTOgod could you add that information to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The programs could be throttling due to the relatively slow read/write speed via the USB cable that is connecting the computer with the external hard drive. The OS could also be throttling the CPU because the two running programs are causing it to overheat, but this is less likely.